# How to run two Maven Mojos with different parameters

Tags: maven, mojo

I wrote a Maven plugin with two Mojos. They are meant to be run in the command line, not attached to any phase of the build.

They happen to have different parameters, and I don't know how to specify them. So far I've managed to use two **executions** one for each one, but it looks clumsy in the command line.

This is the plugin declaration in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>myplugin.tools.camera</groupId>
  <artifactId>camera-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <executions>

    <execution>
      <id>exe1</id>
      <configuration>
        <snapshotfile>file1.shot</snapshotfile>
        <dir>dev</dir>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>take-shot</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>

    <execution>
      <id>exe2</id>
      <configuration>
        <time>12:34.56</time>
        <dir>test</dir> <!-- same parameter, with different value -->
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>show-shot</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>

  </executions>
</plugin>
```

It works, but to run each Mojo I need to run:

```
$ mvn camera:take-shot@exe1
$ mvn camera:show-shot@exe2
```

Would it be possible to get rid of those `@exe1` and `@exe2`?

Now, there could be an advantage to these executions, if I wanted to create multiple different parameters to later pick which one to use. I hoped there could be a default execution, but don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can simply define the default configuration which will be used if you do `mvn camera:take-shot`  via `<id>default-cli</id>`...

Comment: @khmarbaise Works! However, I couldn't set `<id>default-cli</id>` for both cases at the same time. I wanted to mark those two executions as default, each one for each goal.

Comment: You can also remove the executions and put all parameters (for both goals) into the `<configuration>` of the plugin - given that the names of the parameters do not overlap.

Comment: @JFMeier Unfortunately some parameters do overlap, and have different values. Sigh.

Comment: I just tried adding the SAME plugin twice, each one with `default-cli` and a goal. Though it does work, Maven complains that the pom.xml is malformed, and won't work in the future...

Comment: The default-cli id can only be used for a single part cause on the other hand which parameters should be used in the end? You can move the default configuration into the global configuration area of the plugin but this results in having a parameter only once..